# My manager sent me meeting notes after our meeting

Tags: communication, manager

My manager sent me meetings notes after I complained about something. Nothing specific in the notes apart from areas I and the team need to improve on, and some notes about past mistakes (some of them one year old). It is the first time he has sent me notes after the meeting. Why would this be the case?

Comment: I am sorry cannot read his mind. Perhaps ask him?

Comment: `Why would this be the case` Because he's doing his job :) Brownie points from me for organization. Most managers expect _you_ to take and send them notes

Comment: He may want to put it on record.

Answer (score 6):

> Why it can be the case?

If it's the first time, then it's the first time he's decided that he needs to be documenting issues rather than just verbally discussing them.

There could be a lot of reasons behind this decision, not necessarily malicious or bad. The usual reason is to formally make issues known so that they get resolved and are easier to follow up on.

Answer (score 2):

It should be considered to be normal to send out notes after a meeting. That way those who have actionable items to take care of will be reminded of it. 
It also should be considered to be normal to bring up old mistakes. It should not be just to beat up anyone, but so the same thing does not happen again. Perhaps there are new people there or team members have become lax on the issue.
Maybe the fact that you complained during the meeting and the first time the notes were sent out was a coincidence.